# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '_AXIOS_BASE_URL_') adding axios to nuxt 3

Tags: nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

### Using Axios in nuxt 3

I just install nuxt 3 and have this problem when I add `axios` to the project.

[image]

Here my
`nuxt.config.ts`:

```js
import { defineNuxtConfig } from 'nuxt3'

export default defineNuxtConfig({

    buildModules: [

        ['@nuxtjs/axios',{proxyHeaders:false,baseUrl:'http://localhost:8000'}]

    ],


})
```

And clean `cmd`

```
Nuxt CLI v3.0.0-27414150.3589a2d                                                                              19:19:20
                                                                                                              19:19:20
  > Local:    http://localhost:3000/
  > Network:  http://192.168.241.182:3000/

i Vite warmed up in 529ms                                                                                     19:19:23
i Vite warmed up in 496ms                                                                                     19:19:23
√ Vite server built in 863ms                                                                                  19:19:24
√ Nitro built in 195 ms
```

Comment: you can not use axios module as it is not yet compatiable with nuxt 3 yet, you should consider using the fetch for data fetching needs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because nuxt is finding the `_AXIOS` env variable that did not exists in your project.
Just use `useFetch()`. Doing so will make your life easier.
If you are still confused, just use something like this:

https://gist.github.com/amm834/ddadd563102f45e37846d9f2dc9c3594

```js
/**
 * It takes a URL and options, and returns a response object
 * @param url - The URL to fetch.
 * @param [options] - The options object that will be passed to the fetch function.
 * @returns The return value of the useFetch hook.
 */
import {useFetch, useRuntimeConfig} from "nuxt/app";

export default function useFetchApi(url, options = {}) {
    const config = useRuntimeConfig();

    return useFetch(url, {
        ...options,
        baseURL: config.public.apiBase,
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot of this lately, people trying to install nuxt2 modules on nuxt3.
If you don't have special need to specifically use Axios, you could use internal composable useFetch()

Example:

```
const { data, pending, error, refresh } = await useFetch(
  'https://api.nuxtjs.dev/mountains',
  {
    pick: ['title']
  }
)
```

Or $fetch helper - Nuxt uses ohmyfetch to expose globally the $fetch helper for making HTTP requests within your Vue app or API routes.

During server-side rendering, calling $fetch to fetch your internal API routes will directly call the relevant function (emulating the request), saving an additional API call.

Note that $fetch is the preferred way to make HTTP calls in Nuxt 3 instead of @nuxt/http and @nuxtjs/axios that are made for Nuxt 2.